# IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION scope

Tags: sql-server, transactions, scope

What is the scope of

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
```

For example, if I accidentally leave it `ON`, in which case will it be reset to `OFF` (autocommit). I am aware that if I open a new query window, the setting is reset by default for that window, meaning at least at session level the setting is reset. Will it be reset at lower scope, for example function, procedure, batch, etc., if the `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` is set inside these scopes ?

Comment: Valid question, but my advice is to not use non-standard settings if possible. Especially not the dangerous ones like IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS and ansi nulls etc. This creates code that nobody understands and you can't use other peoples code.